# Async Lambda function returning null on calling DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, dynamodb-queries

I am new to async functions and promises. I  have written a Lambda function which queries a DynamoDB table and returns the result. The code is executing inside the callback success block and I am able to see the response in the log from the console.log(res) line. However the Lambda response is always showing as null, i.e. the response object below is not returned at all. I was able to make this work using a Synchronous Lambda function using a callback to return the data. Can you please suggest what I may be doing incorrectly.

```
const doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamodbclient;
const tablename = process.env.TABLE_NAME;

exports.handler = async(event) => {

    if (!dynamodbclient) {
        dynamodbclient = new doc.DynamoDB();
    }

    let id = event.params.id;
    let queryparams = {
        TableName: 'table-name',
        Key: { id: id }
    };[![enter image description here][1]][1]

    var getItemsCallback = (err, res) => {
        console.log('inside');
        if (err) {

        }
        else {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(res);
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
            };
            return response;
        }
    };

    var item = await dynamodbclient.getItem(queryparams, getItemsCallback).promise();
};
```

Comment: you would want to `await getItem(queryParams).promise().then(getItemsCallback)`

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is still executing after the promise resolves, so the lambda will terminate and your callback will not finish.

Try:

```
try {
    const item = await dynamodbclient.getItem(queryparams).promise();
} catch (err) {}

console.log('success');
console.log(item);
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
};
return response;
```